# Switching tab event in notepad ++ using macros

Tags: notepad++, macros

I am trying to do a sequence of operation over one file and wanted to serach key from file1 and take value from file2 hence i am using macro for this in notepad ++

Query is the tab switching Alt+Tab is stuck in macro and hence i cannot capture tab switching in macros in notepad ++ , an anyone please suggest if macro has capability to switch the tab if not then any good alternatives to these.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to switch between files in Notepad++ that are open at the same time. IF it is that, then Alt+Tab is not the shortcut to do that, but Ctrl+Tab. _ALT_ works on windows, _CTRL_ works on tabs

Comment: yes sorry with ctrl +tab , macro is not working to search notepad in one tbal and first formm